# Replicating v4l2loopback command in OSX Big Sur?

Tags: macos, v4l2loopback

I'm trying to replicate the following command in OSX:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=3 card_label="TestVideo"
```

So far I've tested the following advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287784/gstreamer-create-virtual-device-on-osx) but I keep getting an error  `erroneous pipeline: no element "videotestsrc"`

My first question is are the two commands `v4l2loopback=gst-launch-1.0` equal?

My second question is whether there any ways to use `v4l2loopback` in OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first question is are the two commands v4l2loopback=gst-launch-1.0 equal?

no. they are not.

- `gst-launch-1.0` is a command that launches a GStreamer pipeline (as specified by its arguments). [GStreamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer) is a generic, cross-platform media framework
- `v4l2loopback` is not a command at all.

> My second question is whether there any ways to use v4l2loopback in OSX?

no.

the `v4l2loopback` (which is an abbreviation for "video for linux (version 2) loopback") integrates tightly with the *linux kernel*.
the *kernel* is the core component of your operating system. a Linux kernel is not compatible with a Darwin kernel (which is what runs your OSX)